# Please merge "the-terminator-series" tag into "terminator"

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[the-terminator-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-terminator-series) tag is simply unnecessary. Please, create synonym. I don't think someone would like to oppose.

**Update:**
The first movie name and the franchise name matches, but we never needed separate tags for each so far (anyone can easily mention that in the question if they need answer from the first movie only which isn't practical). An example: [the-matrix](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-matrix)

Comment: This might have been better received if it was phrased as a question rather than an instruction. *“I think tagA is unnecessary, should we merge it into tagB? Does anybody have any objections?”* As it stands, it feels a bit abrasive: *“I don't think someone would like to oppose.”*

Comment: He did say "please".

Answer (score 10):

I can see the point of editing the name to make it a bit clearer ( [terminator-franchise](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminator-franchise) perhaps?) but not the point of deleting the entire tag.

There's a world of difference between Terminator (The 1984 film) and Terminator (the entire fictional universe that covers films, a TV series, comics, graphic novels and novels)

Comment: That's understood thing. There are lots of tags such way. For example, *the-matrix* which is used for entire franchise too.

Comment: @SachinShekhar - That's a pretty fair argument for creating a new tag for [tag:Matrix-Franchise] and disambiguating the existing [tag:Matrix] tag

Comment: Then, who is going to edit all those questions and flood the home?

Comment: BTW, the-matrix was just an example. There are countless more.